amazon lambda using gpg
I use amazon lambda on Amazon Linux 2023. Additionally I use a layer with only 1 file - gpg.
But when trying to call
/opt/gpg --decrypt --batch --passphrase "passphrase" -o output.txt input.gpg

I get the message:
gpg: uncompressing failed: Unknown compression algorithm.
Please tell me how to solve the problem
I know that a similar problem on EC2 Amazon linux is solved like this:
dnf swap gnupg2-minimal gnupg2-full

Calling ldd /opt/gpg on lambda shows that it uses libz.so.1 (zlib) and libbz2.so.1 (bzip2) and other libs are available. (the use of these libraries distinguishes gpg installed via the gnupg2-full meta package ).

sloved: I just create the new "layer" with statically linked gpg.
The idea was found here
